# How to use modman in existing git repository

Tags: git, magento, amazon-web-services, modman

I am wondering how to use modman in projects that already have existing .git source control.

Namely consider the following structure.

```
magento_root
-.git
-.gitignore
-.modman
  -extension1
     -.git
     -*-no files will be committed!
  -extension2
     -.git
     -*-no files will be committed!
-app
-other_files
-...
```

The issue is, when locally adding extensions via modman, and after testing them, I would like to push changes up to our production servers (multi-server setup using AWS Elastic Beanstalk), but by default git omits all other .git repositories under its path. This means, that I can successfully install extensions using modman locally, and all the necessary files will be created, but it won't work once I do

```
git add .
git commit -a 
git push or git aws.push
```

because all actual files modman checked out will not be included.

How can I include files modman adds using git, and preserve local development, then push to production software life cycle?

Answer (score 0):

Modman creates symbolic links within the magento file structure, and they should be managed seperately from the git flow of the rest of the site as they are seperate repositories. That said you can set up a bash script on production server that will pull from all of them. Such as:

```
#!/bin/bash
git pull origin master
modman update-all
```

Then just run that when you want everything to be up to date with the repositories.